# How to change anchor text color when hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navigation where right side i am displaying logged in user name in below list item, when first time page loads it set to `background-color #857363` and text set to `#fff` , now when i hover over i can not see the text because visited links are set to white.

How can i target just below anchor tag and make text color black when its hover,visited and active ?

main.html

```
<li style="margin-right: 0;" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right kendoMenuBorder"
    ng-show="user.isAuthenticated"><a>
    {{user.customUserDetails.workFullName}} </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a ui-sref="app.logout"> Logout </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

main.css

```
.kendoMenuBorder {
    color:#fff !important;
    background-color:#857363 !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    li.kendoMenuBorder a {
        color:#fff !important;
    }
    li.kendoMenuBorder a:visited a:hover {
        color:#000000 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your selector. Actually you have to use `multiple selector` at this context.

```
li.kendoMenuBorder a:visited,li.kendoMenuBorder a:hover {
  color:#000000 !important;
}
```

Your selector `li.kendoMenuBorder a:visited a:hover` is wrong as it will set to change color when `anchor` inside `:visited anchor` hovered.

Comment: here is small issue now when i hover over anchor tag for user detail its displaying black color thats good but logout that is drop menu item of anchor tag is coming white and i can not see the text.

Comment: @aftab Can you make a working demo like this? https://jsfiddle.net/krdd6bvn/ so that it would be easy for us to answer you better

Comment: sorry no access to any of those sites

Comment: You might want to include `li.kendoMenuBorder a:active` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to using `!important` attribute everywhere. I think this can be solved by changing priorities within CSS by assigning an id to

```
li.kendoMenuBorder a {
        color:#fff !important;
    }
```

section instead of keeping it as a class.

`!important` overrides everything, you should avoid using it.

Comment: Hi Enes, welcome to StackOverflow! While we do welcome suggestions, answers should be reserved for concrete solutions that you are sure works to resolve the issue at hand. In this case, your answer might be more valued if you gave a workable example

Comment: Hi shrmn. Ok, I'll keep this in mind in the future. I was actually planning to add it to the above answer as a comment, but alas, not enough reputation to comment.